# Can we use any user defined encryption method to create user password in CakePHP?

Tags: authentication, cakephp, passwords, password-encryption, user-defined

Can we use any user defined encryption method to create user password in Cake PHP, if yes in which files I need to modify?

Comment: **User defined encryption** doesn't sound very secure. Why can't you use existing cryptographic solutions?

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: How would you use encryption to _create_ a password, did you mean to store a password?

Comment: Yes, I meant to store password in DB

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify version, but it surely is possible in CakePHP 3.

http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#creating-custom-password-hasher-classes

I guess you need it for fallback reasons, otherwise, AFAIK cakephp security is great.